# Android Studio I don't know why it doesn't show result

Tags: android

I code a simple app by Android Studio, but when I run it on my smartphone, it's not display result on tv_kq (textView). I don't know Where error is. Please help me.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    et_a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et_b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et_c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    tv_kq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new click_ok());

}
class click_ok implements Button.OnClickListener{
public void OnClick(View v){

                int a = Integer.parseInt(et_a.getText().toString());
                int b = Integer.parseInt(et_b.getText().toString());
                int c = Integer.parseInt(et_c.getText().toString());
                int delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

                if (a == 0)
                {
                    if (b == 0)
                    {
                        if (c==0) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có vô số nghiệm");
                        else tv_kq.setText("Phương trình vô nghiệm");
                    }
                    else tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có 1 nghiệm: " +(-c/b));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (delta < 0 ) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình vô nghiệm");
                    else if (delta == 0 ) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có nghiệm kép: "+ (-b/(2*a)));
                    else if (delta > 0) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có 2 nghiệm phân biệt: "+ (((-b)+Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a))+" và "+(((-b)-Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)));
                }

        }
```

Comment: did you implements onclicklistener?

Comment: Do you tried to debug it? Put a break in the onClick method of the click_ok class and see it is being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(et_a.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(et_b.getText().toString());
            int c = Integer.parseInt(et_c.getText().toString());
            int delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

            if (a == 0)
            {
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    if (c==0) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có vô số nghiệm");
                    else tv_kq.setText("Phương trình vô nghiệm");
                }
                else tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có 1 nghiệm: " +(-c/b));
            }
            else
            {
                if (delta < 0 ) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình vô nghiệm");
                else if (delta == 0 ) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có nghiệm kép: "+ (-b/(2*a)));
                else if (delta > 0) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có 2 nghiệm phân biệt: "+ (((-b)+Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a))+" và "+(((-b)-Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)));
            }
    }
});
```

in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this: bt1.setOnClickListener(new click_ok());

to this: bt1.setOnClickListener(this);

and using the standard onClick callback:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:

            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but it doesn't work.
It shows this error https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2014/12/25/Screenshot19.png

Comment: Oh, my suggestion would be if you had your main activity defined like this:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {...

I see you've updated your snips. I'm not experienced enough to know whether button.onclicklistener will work.

It looks like Waki's anonymous class could work.

Comment: Oh, it ran. but when i click button_ok on app it didn;t show result on TextView4.

Answer (score 0):

try to add like this it will solve your error

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

`bt1.setOnClickListener(this);` `//dont forget to implement View.OnClickListener to your mainActivity`

then use onClick callback:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:

            // do stuff

int a = Integer.parseInt(et_a.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(et_b.getText().toString());
            int c = Integer.parseInt(et_c.getText().toString());
            int delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

            if (a == 0)
            {
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    if (c==0) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có vô số nghiệm");
                    else tv_kq.setText("Phương trình vô nghiệm");
                }
                else tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có 1 nghiệm: " +(-c/b));
            }
            else
            {
                if (delta < 0 ) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình vô nghiệm");
                else if (delta == 0 ) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có nghiệm kép: "+ (-b/(2*a)));
                else if (delta > 0) tv_kq.setText("Phương trình có 2 nghiệm phân biệt: "+ (((-b)+Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a))+" và "+(((-b)-Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)));
            }
            break;
    }
}
```